# Make sed to ignore multi-line single or double quoted block

Tags: bash, sed

Suppose I have a shell script with the following content:

```
    echo "This is a single-line text"

    echo "
Examples:   1
            2
            3
            4
    "
```

Now what I want is to cut out the excess space from the beginning of each line:

I'm not any expert at using `sed`, so what I've tried so far was `sed -i 's|^    ||' file`, but this matches from within the multi-line quoted block as well which I don't want it to.

`sed -i 's|^    ||' file` ends up with:

```sh
echo "This is a single-line text"

echo "
Examples:   1
        2
        3
        4
"
```

But I expected it to be like:

```sh
echo "This is a single-line text"

echo "
Examples:   1
            2
            3
            4
"
```

So how could I make sed to ignore such pattern, I'm okay with any `awk` based solution as well.

Thank you.

Comment: `sed 's/^ *echo/echo/' file`?

Comment: I'm not specifically targeting `echo`. I mean any multi-line quoted string. I just want sed to ignore such pattern.

Comment: Logically the leading whitespaces in the last line are also within the double-quoted block and they should not be removed. If you want them to be removed, we need to specify another condition.

Comment: TBH, unless it wouldn't be 1000sends of lines, I would recommend to do that manually in a good text editor. There are so many corner cases, that any solution you write `"requires \"""$( a full blown "shell \" parser")"` anyway. Doing that in sed is close to impossible, as sed is primarily a _line_ editor, multilines are hard in sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- the next-to-last line consists of `4 spaces` + `"`; these spaces should **not** be removed since they are inside the quoted text block
- the last line consists solely of `4 spaces` and will be trimmed to an empty line
- don't have to worry about any edge cases (see KamilCuk's comment)

One `awk` idea based on keeping track of the number of double quotes (`"`) we encounter:

```
awk '
/^    / { if ( qtcnt % 2 == 0 )         # if current line starts with 4 spaces and we
                                        # have seen an even number of double quotes
                                        # prior to this line (ie, we are outside
                                        # of a double quoted string) then ...
             $0=substr($0,5)            # remove the 4 spaces from the current line
        }
        { print $0 }                    # print the current line
        { n=split($0,arr,"\"")          # split the current line on double quotes and
                                        # get a count of the number of fields
          if ( n >=1 )                  # if number of fields >= 1 (ie, line contains
                                        # at least one double quote) then ...
             qtcnt += n - 1             # increment our quote counter
        }
' indent.dat
```

**NOTES**:

- this will erroneously count double quotes in the following situations ...
- escaped double quotes (`\"`)
- single-quoted double quotes (`awk -F'"' ...`)
- double quotes that show up in comments (`# this is a double quote (")`)

If the `print` line is changed to `print "."$0"."` (use periods as visual delimiters) the following is generated:

```
.echo "This is a single-line text".
..
.echo ".
.Examples:   1.
.            2.
.            3.
.            4.
.    ".
..
```

As coded (sans the periods) the following is generated:

```
echo "This is a single-line text"

echo "
Examples:   1
            2
            3
            4
    "
```

**NOTE**: the last line is empty/blank

Comment: This does seem to work well for what I have at my side and yeah your notes are valid but not an issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for gensub() and RT:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS="\""; ORS="" }
NR%2 { $0 = gensub(/(^|\n)[[:blank:]]+/,"\\1","g") }
{ print gensub(/\n[[:blank:]]+$/,"\n",1) RT }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
echo "This is a single-line text"

echo "
Examples:   1
            2
            3
            4
"
```

or with any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS=ORS="\"" }
NR > 1 { print prev }
NR%2 {
    sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/,"")
    gsub(/\n[[:blank:]]+/,"\n")
}
!(NR%2) {
    sub(/\n[[:blank:]]+$/,"\n")
}
{ prev = $0 }
END { printf "%s", prev }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
echo "This is a single-line text"

echo "
Examples:   1
            2
            3
            4
"
```

Caveat: any solution will be fragile unless you write a parser for shell language that can understand when `"` is within strings, within scripts, escaped, etc.